# uncertainty in error propagation of normally distributed data?

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, normal-distribution, measurement-error, error-propagation

I have two normally distributed random variables that add together to form a third normally distributed variable. The means in all cases are 0. Thus, the standard deviations of the first 2 variables add in quadrature:

```
sigma_c^2=sigma_a^2+sigma_b^2
```

I want to measure directly `sigma_a`, but the instrument used adds `sigma_b` noise. Currently I measure (separately) `sigma_b` and `sigma_c`, then solve for `sigma_a`.

The problem is when the instrument noise floor dominates the signal of interest. In the extreme case when this occurs, `sigma_c` (the signal of interest plus noise) approximately equals `sigma_b` (the noise), and my estimate of `sigma_a` (the signal of interest) returns 0, which is incorrect (e.g. I've reached the noise floor of the instrument).

Is it possible to somehow quantify the error in `sigma_a` as `sigma_b` approaches `sigma_c`?

Ultimately I need to determine whether `sigma_a` is below a compliance limit `L` with some amount of certainty. Is this possible given the above data?

UPDATE 1

Is the following true?

"If n samples were taken to compute each of `sigma_c` and `sigma_b`, then the standard error for the signal of interest is `sigma_a`/sqrt(n). Thus, one can be 95% confident that the sample mean of distribution `a` is within plus or minus 1.96*(standard error) from the true population mean."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, averaging reduces the noise. As you already stated 
$$Std[\bar X_n] = Std[X_1]/\sqrt{n}$$ 
where $Std[X_1]$ is the standard deviation and the mean is defined as $$\bar X_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
However, you should be careful, because shifts in the mean could broaden your averaged signal.

Another approach is an experimental one: If you are interested in a periodic signal, maybe you could use a lock-in amplifier to reduce the noise.

Comment: Assuming the $X_i$ variables are IID, shouldn't the variance be reduced by a factor $n$ (instead of $\sqrt{n}$)?

Comment: I'm sorry. As stated, user46688s initial formula is correct, I corrected mine. Thank you, Luca.